# How to terminate a terminal session in a ps1 script

Tags: powershell, shell, terminal, exit, powershell-4.0

How can I terminate a terminal/PowerShell window from a .ps1 script? I would like it to work the way `exit` in command line works, but when I put that in a PowerShell script it only terminates the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Environment.Exit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit) will terminate the whole process:

```
# replace 0 with a non-0 error code if you want to indicate some sort of failure
[Environment]::Exit(0)
```

Comment: I get an error message though

Comment: @norway-yv What did the error message say? :)

Comment: `Environment.Exit : The term 'Environment.Exit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\yrjved08\Downloads\test.ps1:2 char:1
+ Environment.Exit(0)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Environment.Exit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`                                           
                The script was `Environment.Exit(0)`